# Filter AWS Instances By Tags on Specific IP Addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, for-loop, amazon-ec2

I have a bunch of AWS instances with the following private IP addresses

```
10.100.0.1
10.100.0.2
10.100.0.3
10.100.0.4
All the way to 10.100.0.50
```

Is there a way to extract the Private IP address of the instances with IP addresses between `10.100.0.1` and `10.100.0.20` which have specific tags associated to them?

Basically, I want to filter out all the instances that have the following tags `Key=Monitoring Value=True` and `Key=Env Value=Dev`

But I don't want to run the filter command on all my instances. I only want to filter for the above mentioned tags on the instances with IP addresses between `10.100.0.1` and `10.100.0.20`

Is there a way to loop through and get this information using the AWS CLI on a Mac?

Something like `for i in cat IP.txt ; do aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=Running" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[]`

To get the private IP addresses based on specific tags.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I don't want to run the filter command on all my instance"?

Comment: I want to find out which of my instances have the tags key=Monitoring Value=True and Key=Env Value=Dev. 
But I only want to get these tags from the instances with IP addresses between 10.100.0.1 and 10.100.0.20. I don't want to check for tags on instances with IP addresses outside this range.

Comment: You haven't given any indication of how you're trying to do this. Are you using the awscli on Mac, for example, or a specific language SDK like boto3?

Comment: Just updated the question. I'm trying to use the AWS CLI on a Mac

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this.

```
for i in `cat IP` \
do aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=private-ip-address,Values=$i" \
"Name=tag:Monitoring,Values=True" "Name=tag:Env,Values=Dev" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' \
--output text ; done
```

This should give you the private IP addresses of all the instances with the specific tag you're after.